# Save photos on the cloud as encrypted

Tags: photography, encryption, digital-asset-management

I want to save my photos in the cloud, something cheap like Amazon. But I never trust their security.

Is there a software that can encrypt the photos before uploading them, then decrypt them whenever I view them?

Mobile interface is also required.

Comment: Software for what OS(es)? Any price limit?

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion I could provide is [CloudFrogger](https://www.cloudfogger.com/en/), which supports the following:

- AES256 Encryption
- Windows Context Integration
- Windows, iPhone and Android Support

Please note however that this does not really expand on their security.

If unsure, you can use [Mega](https://mega.nz/) which have their source code [here](https://mega.nz/#sourcecode).

I personally believe that [Cryptonite with DropBox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=csh.cryptonite&hl=en) to have an ENCFs is the best option here for you.

Here are some guides for ENCFS:

1. [ENCFS on Linux](http://virtuallyhyper.com/2013/02/sharing-a-file-encrypted-by-encfs-with-android-and-linux-systems-with-google-drive/)
2. [ENCFS on Android](https://thetinhat.com/tutorials/misc/encrypting-the-cloud.html)

Hope this is sufficient.

Comment: Cloudfogger is no longer maintained, they recommend [BoxCryptor](https://www.boxcryptor.com/) now.